# How to validate only one property of model in controller insted of whole model in Spring MVC

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I am new to springMVC so please forgive me if this is simple question.
I have searched a lot on web about this.

In spring we can valdate properties of model in controller like this.For ex.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("abc") Abc abc, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
 {
        // logic
 }
```

My model 'Abc' have 5 properties like this

```
    public class Abc{

     @NotBlank
     @size(min=3)
     @Phone
     String property1;

     @NotNull
     String property2;

     .....
    }
```

Here @Phone is my custom validator.

This controller will validate all 5 properties of model 'Abc' because of `@Valid @ModelAttribute("abc") Abc abc`.

But i dont want this.I just want to validate only 'property1'.

How this is possible?

Comment: simplest is to remove validations from other attributes.

Comment: What i am doing is,First i take inputs form user for all properties.At that time i need to validate all.After that my need is to update only one of that property.At that time i need to validate only one.But at that time `@Valid` will do validation for all 5 properties @Arpit

Comment: Please remove minus vote if now you think this question is valid to ask.@Arpit

Comment: write custom validator for second validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update only one property after the first validation of all 5 (as i can understand from your comment) what you can do is that when you do update of this single property let application go to another RequestMapping so you can not call @Valid but a validator only for this property.

An example would be better maybe:
(This is your submit code)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid        @ModelAttribute("abc") Abc abc,   BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
 {
    // logic
 }
```

When you do your update from a different view: (action of form will point to this)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 Public String    update(@ModelAttribute("abc" Abc abc, BindingResult br, ModelMap model){
 //Custom validation of single property
 /*logic
 ..*/
```

Or maybe you want to update this property in the same method? So simply create only a custom validator only for the property you need and call it when you need.

To create a custom validator you can create a new class that extends 'Validator' of Spring.

Comment: I think this will be redundant validation.right?.Way is good but is there any way so that i can validate particular property only with validation annotation which is already defined in model

Comment: If you want to use only @Valid of spring then you have to put annotations for validation only for the property you need but you won't validate the other four.